# How can I make a query with contains over date/datetime fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm, django-1.6

Im trying to use the datatables jQuery plugin with date/datetime fields. and when you make the query that contains those field generates a [MySQL Warning](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=38915) when you try to use `__contains` in the queryset. I've detected that if you try to make queries over `Year`, `Month` and `Day` the warning doesn't appears.

There's another way to search in a date/datetime field without raise that warning or how could I make a query over a year/month/day in a date/datetime field.

Here is an example:

```
Model.objects.filter(Date__contains="2014")
```

Which gives this warning:

```
Warning: Incorrect date value: '%2014%' for column 'Fecha' at row 1
```

I'd like to make a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Model WHERE YEAR(Date) LIKE "%4%" OR MONTH(Date) LIKE "%4%" OR DAY(Date) LIKE "%4%";
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#year

Comment: @MikeVelazco did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @VinicioAjuchan Yes, my answer

Comment: @MikeVelazco cool, I tried that, but for me it doesn't give me exactly results, I mean sometimes it had weird behaviors, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution that I´ve found is searching by a Regex

```
Model.objects.filter(Date__regex="4")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Model.objects.filter(field_name__year=2014)
```

Comment: if you want to search for a number in any position of the date as it were a string, this doesn´t work. This only filter for a year given.